# How to do JaxB XML Unmarshalling/Marshalling of element with package name?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-binding, jaxb2-basics

I got following XML with element name being present with their package name. How can I marshal/unmarshal the given XML using JaxB?

```
<com.jaraws.api.Vehicle>
  <number>KT12356</number>
  <engine>DIESEL<engine>
</com.jaraws.api.Vehicle>
```

With Java class being written as:

```
package com.jaraws.api;

@XmlRootElement
public class Vehicle{
  private String number;
  private String engine;

  // Getters Setter for number and engine attributes
  @XmlElement
  public String getNumber(){
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(){
    this.number=number;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getEngine(){
    return engine;
  }

  public void setEngine(){
    this.engine=engine;
  }
}
```

Is it achievable or I am not doing something in a right matter. I want to marshal / unmarshal the xml in given format only.

Comment: Did you tried to add a name to the root element? ...like @XmlRootElement(name = "com.jaraws.api.Vehicle")

Comment: @xerx593 and Thomas, if that's the only way of doing that? Can't I avoid writing the package explicitly rather it is getting derived?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Thomas in the comments, just add the `name` attribute to the `@XmlRootElement` annotation to the name you expect :

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "com.jaraws.api.Vehicle")
public class Vehicle {
  // class definition ...
}
```

You can't do something like the following :

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = Vehicle.class.getName())
```

If you try to, you'll get the following error : `The value for annotation attribute XmlRootElement.name must be a constant expression`

By default, according to javadoc, if name is not set, it's derived from the class name :

```java
public @interface XmlRootElement {
    // some stuff

    /**
     * local name of the XML element.
     * <p>
     * If the value is "##default", then the name is derived from the
     * class name. 
     *
     */
    String name() default "##default";
}
```

Not specifying the name element will then lead to the following name `vehicle` (see `org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.model.impl.TypeInfoImpl#parseElementName` method for more info)